# What is the best option for saving lots of coded UITextField text: NSCoding or NSUserDefaults?

Tags: uitextfield, nsuserdefaults, nscoding, uitextfielddelegate

I have an iOS project I'm working on using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift2.  In my project are 30 coded `UITextFields`, each with an assigned `action` for it.  I am also using the `UITextFieldDelegate`.  After the user enters text, I want the text to be saved.  I've searched in here for answers as to the best location to place the save code.  I don't want this project to be taxing on the device's memory.  Is it better to save the text using an `NSObject` and `NSCoding`, something like:

```
class TextFieldSave: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var userText: String = ""
    var textFieldName: String = ""

    ...
}
```

I could then save the name of the `textField` that the text was stored in and save via `NSCoding`.

OR would it be less memory to simply save with `NSUserDefaults`?

I could put the saving code in the action of each `textField` or somehow incorporate all 30 of them in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` section of the `delegate`.  Not sure which is best.  I think `NSUserDefaults` is the simplest, but not necessary the best for memory usage.

Thank you for your advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving via `NSUserDefaults` and the save code is in each `UITextField` `action` I created in code.

```
// Declaration of Variable
var nameDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

In each `action`:

```
nameDefaults.setObject(variable, forKey: "KEYname")
nameDefaults.synchronize()
```

To load these saved values, I created a `function` and run that function in the `ViewWillAppear`.  Works well and does not seem to use the system memory too much.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadData()
}
```

And `loadData` is:

```
if (nameDefaults.objectForKey("KEYname") != nil) {
    variable = (nameDefaults.objectForKey("KEYname") as! String)
    textField.text = variable
    print(variable)
} else {
    print("nil")
}
```